# Node Heroku Env Variable from another env variable

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to set an environment variable for socks proxy. This variable is dependent on ip and port. i.e.

```
socks://23.244.534.344:8080
```

Issue is that in Heroku the port is dynamic. Unfortunately I cannot do this dynamically in my Node code as I need it in a public module. So the question is,

Is there a way to reference another Env Variable in another variable. Or is there a way to build that environment the "socks" environment variable at npm start with the port variable in it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use arbitrary ports on Heroku. Can you explain exactly what you're doing with your proxy? Why is it necessary?

Comment: Here is a link to the node module I'm trying to use. https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api#troubleshooting
You can see the here https://github.com/jaggedsoft/node-binance-api/blob/838796cedf5605d2f5a92647a2af6822baa3ab7f/node-binance-api.js#L434
It refers to a env variable that I have to setup which is a combination of IP and Port

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I'm not going to go offsite and dig through the documentation and source for some random library to try to figure out what you're asking. _Why do you need a proxy?_

Comment: Sorry. The socket listens to activity on prices from the Binance Servers as well as account changes. Somehow I don't need a proxy when in dev environment on my computer but when I deploy to heroku that socket is not receiving anything

Comment: Well. I modified the module so that the proxy is correctly assembled but still no luck. Somehow I can't find any info on this. I think most articles are about having your own websocket in Node but not your server listening to other sockets. Somehow I can't get through

Comment: You need to listen on a second port, aside from your web server port? Two ports at once? I don't think you can do that on Heroku.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I am confused and a bit of a newbie. I guess my node server needs to have a port to listen to another server. So dunno if that is two ports, but likely since there is one for my express server to listen for commands and one for the socket to listen to the other server.